# Does the C# Yield free a lock?

Tags: c#, locking, yield

I have the following method:

```
public static IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> GetRowsIter
   (this SqlCeResultSet resultSet)
{
    // Make sure we don't multi thread the database.
    lock (Database)
    {
        if (resultSet.HasRows)
        {
            resultSet.Read();

            do
            {
                var resultList = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                for (int i = 0; i < resultSet.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    var value = resultSet.GetValue(i);
                    resultList.Add(resultSet.GetName(i), value == DBNull.Value 
                                                                  ? null : value);
                }
                yield return resultList;
            } while (resultSet.Read());
        }
        yield break;
    }
```

I just added the `lock(Database)` to try and get rid of some concurancy issues.  I am curious though, will the `yield return` free the lock on `Database` and then re-lock when it goes for the next iteration?  Or will `Database` remain locked for the entire duration of the iteration?

Comment: See “And `finally`…” in http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter6/IteratorBlockImplementation.aspx

Comment: This is a potentially *extremely bad idea*. It is very difficult to control lock ordering when you can run arbitrary code between when the lock is obtained and the lock is released. This is just asking for deadlocks.

Comment: @Eric Lippert - I am not really too familiar with multithreaded coding.  (Though I am getting better as I go.)  I now know that the "magic" of the lock statement is really just a `try finally` block and that `yield` keeps things in scope while it is in a yielded state.  With this in mind moved the lock to surround just the `for` loop.  That gives me the restriction on the SQL Server CE access that I need while not locking during "off" iteration time.  (At least so I hope!)

Comment: To add to Eric's comment: it's even possible that the code that acquires the lock may run in a different thread from the code that (tries to) releases it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No the `yield return` will not cause any locks to be freed / unlocked.  The `lock` statement will expand out to a `try / finally` block and the iterator will not treat this any differently than an explicit `try / finally` in the iterator method.

The details are a bit more complicated but the basic rules for when a `finally` block will run inside an iterator method is

1. When the iterator is suspended and `Dispose` is called the `finally` blocks in scope at the point of the suspend will run
2. When the iterator is running and the code would otherwise trigger a `finally` the `finally` block runs.
3. When the iterator encounters a `yield break` statement the `finally` blocks in scope at the point of the `yield break` will run

Comment: @Marc made the answer more explicit that it would be handled no differently than any other `try / finally` defined in an iterator method.

Comment: @Marc yeah edited to make my intent more explicit after I read your comment.

Comment: Would moving the lock to only bracket the `for` loop "fix" it so that it would lock and unlock after each iteration?

Comment: @Vaccano that would prevent the lock from being held while the iterator was suspended.  Whether or not that is OK for your application is difficult / impossible to determine without better understanding why the lock exists at all

Answer (score 14):

The lock translates to try/finally (normal C#).

In Iterator blocks (aka yield), "finally" becomes part of the IDisposable.Dispose() implementation of the *enumerator*. This code is also invoked internally when you consume the last of the data.

"foreach" automatically calls Dispose(), so if you consume with "foreach" (or regular LINQ etc), it *will* get unlocked.

However, if the caller uses GetEnumerator() directly (very rare) and **doesn't** read all the data and **doesn't** call Dispose(), then the lock will not be released.

I would have to check to see if it gets a finaliser; it *might* get released by GC, but I wouldn't bet money on it.

Answer (score 5):

The Database object will be locked until iteration finishes (or the iterator is disposed).

This might lead to excessive periods of locking, and I would recommend against doing it like this.

Answer (score 2):

The lock remains in effect until you get outside of the scope of lock(). Yielding does not do that.